# SQL help for table variable/CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Gurus,
I have a table which has log of all customer's shopping details as below. shopmode is a master table id.

```
ShopDate    CustomerId  ShoppingMode
1/1/2011    a                  0
1/1/2011    a                  0
1/1/2011    a                  1
1/1/2011    b                  0
2/1/2011    a                 0
2/1/2011    b                 1
3/1/2011    a                 1
3/1/2011    b                 0
3/1/2011    c                0
```

I am trying to comeup with query for requirements
(date is in dd/mm/yyyy)

1. Show one record per customer on shopdate,customerid,shopmode

> ```
> 1/1/2011  a  0
> 1/1/2011  a  1
> 1/1/2011  b  0
> ```

2. on a given date range(1/1/2011- 3/1/2011), need most recent shop date having unique value of customerid + shopmode

> ```
> 3/1/2011  a    1
> 3/1/2011  b    0
> 3/1/2011  c    0
> 2/1/2011  b    1
> 2/1/2011  a    0
> ```

3. on a given date range(1/1/2011-3/1/2011), the most recent by shopdate for customerid

> ```
> 3/1/2011   a   1    
> 3/1/2011   b   0    
> 3/1/2011   c   0
> ```

Need your help..

```
SELECT Max(shopdate),customerid, shopmode
FROM Table
```

with this result I will be joining shoppingdetail table to show data. Am tring to create a table variable or CTE show that I can join with other table.

Comment: Could you please provide expected output?

Comment: use `row_number()over(partition by ....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: just group by or select distinct

```
with cte1 as (
select ShopDate, CustomerId, ShoppingMode
from table
group by  ShopDate, CustomerId, ShoppingMode)
select * from cte1;
```

2: First, find number of shopping types per day and customer. Then over those with one shopping type, just get the maximum date.

```
with cte2 as (
select ShopDate, CustomerId, max(ShoppingMode), 
      count(distinct ShoppingMode) as cnt
from table
where ShopDate between start_date and end_date
group by  ShopDate, CustomerId
)
select max(ShopDate)as ShopDate, CustomerId, ShoppingMode
from cte2
where cnt = 1
group by Customer_id;
```

3: Just select all customers, rank them, and select what you want:

```
with cust as (   
select 
     CustomerId, 
     row_number() over (partition by customerId order by ShopDate desc) as rnk
from table 
where ShopDate between start_date and end_date
)
select * from cust where rnk = 1
```

Comment: I have around 19 million records.. group by will be heavy.. any other option

Comment: I don't see better options. If you have many rows use parallel hint. Also, an index on ShopDate shoud be useful for second and third queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ShopDate,
               CustomerId,
               ShoppingMode,
               ROW_NUMBER ()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY ShopDate, CustomerId, ShoppingMode
                        ORDER BY ShopDate, CustomerId, ShoppingMode)
                  rn
          FROM yourtable where shopdate >= '01jan2011' AND shopdate <= '03jan2011')
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: for other 2 options also can we use partition by

Comment: for other 2 options, means two more fields ? if fields then you can add in partition by clause and also in order by clause.